# How to close branch in git?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control, git-merge

I don't understant that git. I have the following log displayed in IntelliJ:

[image]

It probably means, that I am on branch `recoveredfromdetachedheadlost` and `master` branch is left far in the past.

How to close that branch `recoveredfromdetachedheadlost` and turn it into master? I can `commit` on any branch, which makes `HEAD` label jumping onto appropriate position. If `commit` to master and then `merge` against `recoveredfromdetachedheadlost`, then `HEAD` just jumps back to top, leaving `master` still in the past.

How to grab `master` and bring it to top?

Comment: Do you want what is on your branch to be in `master`?

Comment: Yes I do. I don't need `recoveredfromdetachedheadlost`

Comment: Right see Flows answer. You can also do this in intellij - switch to master first, be sure it says `master` in the bottom right, and then choose your branch and select `Merge`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to go to master and update it.

Be sure to have a clean working tree.

```
// Go to your master branch
git checkout master 
// Update master branch to recoveredfromdetachedheadlost
git rebase recoveredfromdetachedheadlost
// Delete obsolete branch (if it's on the same commit in your log)
git branch -d recoveredfromdetachedheadlost

[Optional]
// Push your changes to the remote
git push origin master:master
```

Comment: I think I did checkout/merge pair you suggest, but it didn't help.

Comment: does it say `HEAD` `branchname` `master` at the top in the `Log` ?

Comment: No. After I do `git checkout master` then `HEAD` label goes down to `master`, and after I do `git merge recoveredfromdetachedheadlost`, it goes up back. `master` remains below.

Comment: Ok, then try `git rebase recoveredfromdetachedheadlost` instead of the merge. If it ask you to force the rebase, you can do it.

Comment: Seems about right. I wouldn't use `-D` though when deleting. `-d` should be enough and has additional security guards